# Function related to Orange GUI

Tags: orange

I am a beginner to Orange GUI data mining software and I have some questions related to that.

First, I would like to know if there is any search function so that I can search if a column contains a specific word.

Second, does Orange has any functions for dimension reduction?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Orange has a Dimensionality Reduction Widget under the Unsupervised Learning tab. Click PCA (Principal Component Analysis)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Ethan stated you can use the `PCA` widget to reduce the dimensions of your data.

To search internally try the [`select data by index`](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/widgets/data/select-by-data-index.html) widget.